# Expecation of sum of random +-1 vars

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $X_i$ and $Y_i$ be i.i.d. random variables taking on $1$ and $-1$ with probability $\frac12$.
Let $C_n = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i$. What is the expected value of $|C_n|$?

EDIT:

It looks to me like $E|C_n| = \frac{2n\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}}$, at least when $n$ is even... I am trying to prove it. If this is incorrect please let me know.

Comment: Is there any independence here?

Comment: Yes, independent.

Comment: What is independent?

Comment: $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent, so are $X_i$ and $X_j$, so are $Y_i$ and $Y_j$.

Comment: You can replace $X_iY_i$ with a variable $Z_i$ that takes $\pm1$ with probability $\frac24$. It might make it easier for you to answer the question.

Comment: I have added my upper bound? Is this bound correct?

Comment: Yes, but it not very sharp as $n$ grows since $E(|C_n|)$ is really of order $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: How do you see that?

Comment: Hint: CLT + uniform integrability.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the expected value of $|C_n|$? ... How do we tighten this bound?

The best solution to the second question is the answer to the first question: *i.e.* find the exact solution.

Let $Z = X Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are indepedent Rademacher random variables *i.e.* $X$ and $Y$ each independently take -1 or 1 with equal probability. Then $Z$ is also a Rademacher random variable.

Let $U \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\frac12)$ *i.e.* $U = 0$ or $U=1$ with equal probability. Then $Z = 2 U - 1$. Then:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i  \quad =  \quad (2 \sum_{i=1}^n U_i) - n \quad = \quad 2 S -n$$

where $S \sim \text{Binomial}(n,\frac12)$,  since the sum of $n$ Bernoulli's is $\text{Binomial}(n,p)$.

Our Binomial random variable $S$ has pmf $f(s)$:

[image]

We seek:

$$ E\big[ \, \frac1n \left|  \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i \right| \, \big] \quad = \quad E_f \big[ \, {\frac{1}{n} \large    \left |  2 S - n \right| } \, \big]$$

which is derived here using *mathStatica*:

[image]

All done.

Here is a plot of the EXACT solution just derived (Blue dots) as $n$ increases from 1 to 30:

[image]

In the above plot:

- the BLUE dots denote the EXACT solution
- the ORANGE dots plot the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ bound suggested by Simeon [see comments above].

**Notes**

1. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors of the *mathStatica* software used.
2. `Floor[x]` is a *Mathematica* function that gives the greatest integer less than or equal to `x`.

Comment: Is there not a way to see this analytically?

Comment: What part was not analytical?

Comment: How did the program arrive at that expression?

Comment: An algorithm flavoured with 100 exotic herbs and spices.